# Map Kit: Custom placemarks

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, iphone-sdk-3.0, mapkit

how do I use custom placemarks instead of the standard pins with MapKit
on the iPhone?

Regards

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You must extend the MKAnnotationView  class, it has various properties you can set, the image property is t he one concern with the placemark image, and when you use MKPinAnnotationView the image property is the pin...hope that helps

Comment: Thanks, Daniel. Using [pinAnnotations setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"info.png"]]; doesn't work. pinAnnotations is a MKAnnotationView class. Am I missing something?

Comment: whats coming out as the image for the pin then nothing?

Comment: Are you sure you arent using MKPinAnnotationView , MKAnnotationView doesnt know anything about the pin i dont think

Comment: In your mapView:viewForAnnotation method set annotationView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"custom_pin.png"]. Be careful to make it big enough so it scales properly.